# Spring Centralized Configuration with Data source configurations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am learning Spring cloud Centralized Configuration and  trying to build new application using it,

Followed the steps from [Spring Centralized Configuration](http://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) it is working as expected if controller properties are centralized.

Do we have a way to centralized all the properties like data source or the properties used in @bean declarations, which can picked at the startup of the application.

I want to understand best practices to use the Spring Centralized Configuration to move all the configurations in one place.

Thanks,

Comment: anything you put in a local application.properties can be put in config server.

Comment: Corrected typo in title